# JSON API Call: Pagination loop - unable to increment offset value

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make an API call which has a 50 records per call limit, the JSON response gives me "objects" and "total_objects".

I am running into an issue with the code that i managed to put together with help, the output does increment from the 50th record till the 95th record, post which it loops back to print from the 45th record and loops with the same set.

issue: stuck in a loop where the increment is one record at a time and a repeat of 49 old records

```
 var client_id = 'xxxx';
    var client_secret = 'xxx';
    var email = 'xxx';
    var password = 'abc';
    var device = '1';
    var app_version = '1';
    var Token = 'abcde';

    // call the API to get data for your list
    function AP_Hyd() {
        // URL and params for the API
        var root = 'https://abcdef:443//v2/';
        var endpoint = 'ghij/3241/objects?search=rtewq&limit=50&offset=';
        var offset = '0'
        // parameters for url fetch
        var params = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'muteHttpExceptions': true,
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Token
            }
        };
        // call the API for first offset
        var json = getAssetData(root,endpoint, offset, params);
        var totalObjects = json.objects;
        //Adding data to ActiveGoogleSheet
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        sheet.clear()
        //Adding Column Headings
        var headerRow = ['erwf', 'gtre', 'poi', 'hgf', 'lkj', 'zyx'];
        sheet.appendRow(headerRow);
        //print first batch
        printRows(totalObjects,sheet);
        //check for any further data available
        if (totalObjects) {
            let totalPages = json.totals.objects;
            //get total number of pages to be retrieved
            var pageCount = parseInt(totalPages / 50)
           
             //check for decimal
            //if decimal is found increase the value of pageCount by 1
            if(totalPages%50 !=0){
              pageCount++;
            }
            Logger.log("pageCount:::" + pageCount +" for total objects:: " + totalPages);
           for (i = 1; i < pageCount; i++) {
                //invoke again and lets say the response is added in response
                // call the API with incremented offset
                var pageResponse = getAssetData(root,endpoint, i, params);
                var jsonObjects = pageResponse.objects;
                //print the rows 
                printRows(jsonObjects,sheet);
            }
        }
    }
    function getAssetData(root,endpoint,offset, params){
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root + endpoint + offset, params);
        var content = response.getContentText()
        //return the parsed content
        //TODO: add null check
        return JSON.parse(content)
    }
    function printRows(jsonData, sheet) {
        if (jsonData) {
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                var fieldObj = jsonData[i];
                
                ;
                Logger.log(fieldObj)
                // print out all the Columns
                
                sheet.appendRow(row);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use code snippets for scripts that cannot be run without external dependencies or platforms. Use proper code formatting [Ctrl+K] instead: single backticks (“`”) for one-liners, property names and methods, code fences (“````”) for code blocks. Also please avoid chit-chat in questions, SO is not a forum, it is a Q&A website.

Comment: How many records are there in total (`totalPages`)?

Comment: 4000+ records and increasing

Comment: It is hard to reproduce for me since I do not have access to your API. Is the `for` loop being executed the expected amount of time? Is your error related to receiving wrong data? Wirting wrong data? Looping the wrong amount of times or in a wrong order? Implement [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to make sure that your requests are being performed synchronically and not in parallel. Try to debug by implementing plenty of logs.

Comment: Thank you for your response, debugged line by line and figured out the cause. Was incrementing the offset value page wise (1,2,3) instead of records (+50 limit). Thank you again for your time.